# How to calculate the L1 and L2 norm of angle values wrt the ground truths (where Angle values have a -180 to 180 period)?

Tags: math, computer-vision, rotation, angle, visual-odometry

How to calculate the L1 and L2 norm of angle values wrt the ground truths (where Angle values have -180 degrees to 180 degrees period)?

If I have an array of data `ip_data[]` and an array of ground truth values `gt[]` then the L1 and L2 norm can be calculated:

```
L1 norm = sum(abs(gt[i] - ip_data[i]))

L2 norm = sqrt(sum( (gt[i] - ip_data[i])^2 ))
```

However, generally, in the case of the angle values, they have -180 degrees to 180 degrees period. So, let's say

```
gt[] = [175, 179, 177]

ip_data_a[] = [165, 169, 167]

ip_data_b[] = [-175, -171, -173]
```

For `ip_data_a[]`,

```
L1 = |175 - 165| + |179 - 169| + |177 - 167| = 30
L2 = sqrt(10^2 + 10^2 + 10^2) = sqrt(300)    = 17.32
```

For `ip_data_b[]`,

```
L1 = |175 - (-175)| + |179 - (-171)| + |177 - (-173)| = 1050
L2 = sqrt(350^2 + 350^2 + 350^2) = sqrt(367500)       = 606.22
```

As can be seen, there is a huge difference in `L1`(or `L2`) for `ip_data_a[]` v/s `ip_data_b[]` even though all the values in both the data array are exactly 10 degrees away from the ground truth except in opposite directions.

Normalizing these angles from [-180, 180] to [0, 360] does not help. Because the same thing will happen when the GT angle is close to 360 deg and the given angle value is close to 0 deg or vice-versa.

So, in this type of scenario/data, what is the correct way of calculating the L1 and L2 norm so that data can be assessed properly?

Comment: that's just arithmetic, right? figure out the proper math so that your signed differences (of target and actual) lie between -180 and +180. that takes some addition and modulo and subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem roundabout, but it may be easier to go through the trigonometric functions if confusing to  the discontinuous boundary of angle value.
Since the value of `sin` and `cos` are continuous, the problem disappears automatically!

That is, solve the angles between the unit vectors. e.g. the angle can be obtained from arc-cosine of inner-product.

Unit vector for angle is `[cos(angle), sin(angle)]^T` as you know.
`cos( a - b )` is inner-product between 2 unit vectors : `cos(a)cos(b) + sin(a)sin(b)`.
So, the "difference" between the two angles `a`,`b` is arc-cosine of this.

---

If you want simple arithmetic way, it will like as below.
This returns "L1 norm".

```cpp
//a and b are angle(degree) and in range [-180, 180].
double DiffAngle( double a, double b )
{
    //Because of the input range constraint, this value can not be greater than 360.
    double Raw = fabs(a-b);  //|a-b|
    //When the above value becomes over 180, desired value will be this.
    double Opposite = 360 - Raw;
    //So what you need is to choose one of them.
    return (std::min)( Raw, Opposite );  //choose smaller one
}
```

Comment: I think this way is not best but easy. Here, "Easy" means "can avoid some confusion from discontinuous boundary of angle value".

Comment: I think a modulo operation is quite a bit simpler…

Comment: I seems that OP are confusing about such a arithmetics. So, I posted another way which can avoid the confusion. (I already said as "roundabout", "this way is not best")

Comment: My comment was deleted. Now I can't understand what you want. You want to force me to post about the modulo? Why don't by yourself?

Comment: It's just a comment. Don't fret about it. I'm sure your answer will give OP some insight into the problem.

Comment: I understand. But now I also added a simple arithmetic method.